# About transaction performance issue in node postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am a newbie to node.js, and meet a problem about transaction in node-pg.
In MVC, we use transaction via sqlcommand with sql string directly, like following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @M int,@D int ,@S int ,@R int 
INSERT INTO purchase_m
(purchase_id)
VALUES
('PUR1')
SELECT @M = @@ERROR
INSERT INTO purchase_d
(purchase_id,seq,prod_id,QTY)
VALUES
('PUR1','1','PROD1',100)
SELECT @D = @@ERROR
UPDATE stock
SET QTY = QTY + 100
WHERE prod_id = 'PROD1'
SELECT @S = @@ERROR
SELECT @R = @@ROWCOUNT
IF @M = 0 AND @D = 0 AND @S = 0 AND @R = 1
COMMIT TRANSACTION
ELSE
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Howerver, in node-pg, things go different. the code example in web like belows:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg'
const pool = new Pool()
const client = await pool.connect()
try {
  await client.query('BEGIN')
  const queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
  const res = await client.query(queryText, ['brianc'])
 
  const insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO photos(user_id, photo_url) VALUES ($1, $2)'
  const insertPhotoValues = [res.rows[0].id, 's3.bucket.foo']
  await client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues)
  await client.query('COMMIT')
} catch (e) {
  await client.query('ROLLBACK')
  throw e
} finally {
  client.release()
}
```

but it somehow make me confused, since I/O waiting time is wasted for each query, it somehow
conflict the methodology we use in developing .NET applications. Is there any materials to explain why node-pg use this to commit transaction, and would this way block the table(e.g.,users) we use during these queries execution? Any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Removed `pg-promise` tag, because you do not use it here.

Comment: Is this issue should be consider when developing transaction in node.js? there seems not many materials to discuss this.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between .net and nodejs or the difference between sql server and postgres? You can actually combine them in any combination.

Comment: You can use [stored procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) or [`DO` blocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-do.html) with your favourite [procedural language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html) in postgres as well. However, the example you found shows how to actually use a transaction that processes data on the application server (in node.js), which is more common than doing things with SQL scripts only.

Comment: I am worried about the sequence client query commands will delay the complete time of transaction, and the other sql command requests may be block between these intervals, thanks.